# Extended debugging log when starting FTK Imager using wine on MacOS

Tags: macos, drivers, wine

Lately I managed to install Program I am frequently using for restoring files I mistakenly deleted on various drives of mine. Program is called FTK Imager.
Version of Wine HQ I am using is 8.0.1. It is the most recent version of Wine I think at least (Wine Stable). Operating System I am using is macOS Monterey 12.6.6.

Using wine64 I can run it and it works with no problems. However when I start a program I have this extended log below listing in my terminal window. Is this something I should be worried about? Are there any dependencies or underlying issues with my system?

```
00b0:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
00b0:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
00b0:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
00b0:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
00a8:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000142
003c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"wineusb" failed to start: 1114
0024:fixme:nls:RtlGetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 000000000011F284, 000000000011F2A0 000000000011F280
0024:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 0x809 000000000011F284 000000000011F2A0 000000000011F280) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0024:fixme:nls:RtlGetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 000000000011F1E4, 000000000011F200 000000000011F1E0
0024:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 0x809 000000000011F1E4 000000000011F200 000000000011F1E0) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0024:fixme:nls:RtlGetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 000000000011EBB4, 000000000011EBD0 000000000011EBB0
0024:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 0x809 000000000011EBB4 000000000011EBD0 000000000011EBB0) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0124:fixme:sync:SetWaitableTimerEx (00000000000000CC, 00000000045DF730, 0, 0000000000000000, 0000000000000000, 00000000009CF000, 250) semi-stub
0024:fixme:msg:pack_message msg 14 (WM_ERASEBKGND) not supported yet
0024:fixme:shell:InitNetworkAddressControl stub
0024:fixme:ieframe:PersistStreamInit_Load (00000000033C0D70)->(000000000011CEC8)
0024:fixme:ieframe:OleControl_FreezeEvents (00000000033C0D70)->(1)
0024:fixme:ieframe:OleControl_FreezeEvents (00000000033C0D70)->(0)
0024:fixme:ieframe:navigate_url Unsupported args (Flags 000000000011D0A8 {VT_INT: 14}; TargetFrameName (null))
0130:fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyIpInterfaceChange (family 0, callback 0000000004B78F20, context 0000000003453FA0, init_notify 0, handle 0000000009B8FA90): stub
0024:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0024:fixme:imm:ImmGetDescriptionW (0000000000000415, 0000000000000000, 0): semi stub
0024:fixme:imm:ImmGetDescriptionW (0000000000000415, 000000000CABC0F8, 9): semi stub
0024:fixme:msctf:InputProcessorProfileMgr_GetActiveProfile (00000000002CB760)->({34745c63-b2f0-4784-8b67-5e12c8701a31} 0000000000119A10)
0024:fixme:file:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0024:fixme:ieframe:BrowserService_GetTravelLog 000000000CD0EBF0 000000000011A500
0024:fixme:mshtml:on_change_dlcontrol unsupported dlcontrol 40008790
0024:fixme:ieframe:ClientSite_GetContainer (00000000033C0ED0)->(000000000011A4A8)
0024:fixme:ieframe:ClientSite_GetContainer (00000000033C0ED0)->(000000000011ADA8)
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch igno
red due to missing DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0 (t=74.9771) [GFX1]: Potential driver version m
ismatch ignored due to missing DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0
0024:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (000000000001005A, 1): stub
0024:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000010070, 000000000001005A): stub
0110:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (000000000002002A, 0): stub
0110:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000020036, 000000000002002A): stub
0024:fixme:ieframe:DocHostUIHandler_GetDropTarget (00000000033C0ED0)
0058:fixme:mountmgr:query_property Faking StorageDeviceProperty data
0058:fixme:mountmgr:query_property Faking StorageDeviceProperty data
0058:fixme:mountmgr:query_property Faking StorageDeviceProperty data
0058:fixme:mountmgr:query_property Faking StorageDeviceProperty data
0024:fixme:ntdll:EtwRegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {a3da04e0-57d7-482a-a1c1-61da5f95bacb}
0024:fixme:ntdll:EtwRegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {917b96b1-ecad-4dab-a760-8d49027748ae}
0024:fixme:ntdll:EtwRegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {26d1e091-0ae7-4f49-a554-4214445c505c}
0024:fixme:ieframe:PropertyNotifySink_OnChanged unimplemented dispid 1005
0024:fixme:ieframe:OleInPlaceObject_InPlaceDeactivate (00000000033C0D70)
0024:fixme:ieframe:ControlSite_OnFocus (00000000033C0ED0)->(0)
0024:fixme:ieframe:InPlaceSite_OnInPlaceDeactivateEx fNoRedraw (1) ignored
0024:fixme:mshtml:DocObjHlinkTarget_SetBrowseContext (00000000033C63F0)->(0000000000000000)
```